# Find the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by the curves $y=x^2$, $x=4$ and $y=0$ about the $x$-axis

Tags: calculus

I do not understand how they want the volume between $y=x^2$ and $y=0$? I don't understand how to do the problem. Please help. I have other similar homework problems and would like to LEARN how to do them properly.

Comment: If you look at the Cartesian $x$-$y$ plane, there are three curves (one curve and two straight lines) that define something like a triangle.  Now imagine the $z$ axis out of your paper and you are in a 3D space.  Take the $x$ axis and imagine that the curved triangle rotates producing a curved cone.  That's the volume you are supposed to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to find the area between the given curves. I like to draw a picture. Here we have a parabola $y=x^2$ and two lines $x=4$, which is a vertical line, and $y=0$, which actually is just the x axis. Think now of rotating this area around the x axis. You get a sort of bell or horn shaped thing. What if we cut this horn into really thin disks that are circles with radius $x^2$ going perpendicular to the x axis? We could find their volume, add it up, and get the total volume.

This should make you think of an integral.

The volume of each thin disk I mentioned is $\pi r^2$ times the disk thickness "dx", which we could also write as $\Delta x$. The radius r of each disk is $x^2$. So, en total we can form an integral $\int_0^4 \pi (x^2)^2 dx=\int_0^4 \pi (x^4)dx$.

Maybe consult a good calculus text to see more methods.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understood your explanation very well. I ended up getting Volume=(1024/5)pi